# Large numbers conversion to Byte in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Why does a `double` of `65555` converted to `byte` produce a result of `19` in Kotlin?

Answer (score 9):

That's because of a numerical conversion from a wider type to a type of a smaller size. The `Double` ([IEEE 754 double precision number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) has its integral part factored to the powers of two as 
65555 = 2<sup>17</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup> = 65536 + 16 + 2 + 1, which is stored in binary form as (higher bits to lower):

```
 ‭... 0 1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1‬
```

When this number is converted to `Byte`, only its lowest 8 bits are retained:

```
 ... _ ‭_  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1‬
```

And that results into 2<sup>4</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup> = 16 + 2 + 1 = 19.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you convert 65555 (or 65555.0) to a binary representation it takes more than one byte. So calling `.toByte()` takes the lowest one, which is 19.

```
65555 -> Binary == 1 00000000 00010011
                   ^ ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
                   1     0       19
```

Answer (score 1):

Double 65555.0 gets converted to integer 65555 which is 0x10013. Conversion to Byte takes lower byte which is 0x13 (19 decimal).